# Is $-1$ a perfect square?

Tags: complex-numbers, square-numbers

> Is $-1$ a perfect square?

We know that $i^2 = -1$. Does that mean $-1$ is a perfect square because $i$ is not an irrational or decimal number?

Comment: In the ring of Gaussian integers $\mathbf Z[i]$, yes.

Comment: What is your definition of perfect square? The usual definition says it's the square of an integer.

Comment: Normally, we call a number a perfect square if it is the square of an integer. And with integer here we mean *rational* integer, i.e., no complex numbers allowed

Comment: @Crostul, I'm more asking if it is a perfect square using general terms, so whatever the generally accepted definition of a perfect square is.

Comment: It is a perfect square but not a square number.

For it to be a square number, $i$ would have to be an integer.

Comment: What do you mean by "decimal number"? This is not a term used by mathematicians, at least not in a way that makes sense here.

Comment: Every complex number is the square of some complex number, so a small modification would lead to "all complex numbers are perfect squares". In this case, the name "perfect square" will not make sense anymore. But if we restrict to $\mathbb Z[i]$, a definition would make some sense because not every number will be a square of some other number.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The term *perfect square* is typically reserved for squares of integers, unless further context is specified, so in the regular usage of the term, $-1$ is not a perfect square.

More generally, you might want to refer to perfect squares in a [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)) (especially the [ring of integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_integers) of an algebraic number field)—in such a context, we might say that $-1$ is a perfect square, but with reference to the ring. For example, $-1$ is a perfect square in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, but is not a perfect square in $\mathbb{Z}$.

This situation is similar to how $i$ is not an irrational number—the term *irrational number* refers to real numbers which are not rational, not just any old mathematical entity which is not a rational number.

Comment: @BillDubuque, your link is to an ebay listing!  Also, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_number seems to agree with Clive's convention here that irrational numbers are necessarily real, so that $i$ is, by that convention, not irrational.

Comment: Your last sentence is inaccurate - see [Is $i$ irrational?](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/823981/242)  @Barry see the linked thread (link now fixed).  The point is that the definition / convention depends on the context (just as for squares).

Comment: @BillDubuque, thanks for fixing the link.  It's a nice answer there.  I'm a little surprised the wikipedia entry doesn't make any mention of the alternative convention.