# Prove that $ i^i$ is transcendental.

Tags: complex-numbers, irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

I just learned that $i^i \approx 0.20788$ is transcendental.
Can anyone  detail a proof?

Comment: By Gelfond-Schneider theorem...

Comment: The definition of $i^i$ however is not unique. It depends on the branch we use for the logarithm. But the gelfond-schneider-theorem guarantees that all those numbers are transcendental. The number chosen in the question can also be expressed by $\large e^{-\pi/2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $i$ is algebraic ($\neq0,1$) and $i$ is irrational, a deepish [theorem due to Gelfond and Schneider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem) implies that $i^i$ is transcendental.

Comment: Whether $i$ is irrational depends on your definition. See, e.g., [this question (link).](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823970/is-i-irrational)

Comment: Sorry this was unnecessarily complicated at first. The reason was that I initially started tracing it back to the transcendence of Gelfond's constant $e^\pi$. For some reason I posted a version where G-S was applied to $(-1)^{i/2}$.

Comment: The definition used for Gelfond-Schneider: irrational means, not a quotient $a/b$ where $a,b \in \mathbb Z$, $b \ne 0$.  So in particular $i/2$ is irrational.  Makes sense for complex numbers, and is the standard definition.  Makes sense for $p$-adic numbers, too.  For example, if $\sqrt{-1}$ exists in a $p$-adic field, then its $p$-adic expansion is not eventually periodic.

Comment: @user236182 Whether Gelfond-Schneider theorem applies to the exponent $i$ most emphatically does **not** depend on your definition of an irrational number.

Comment: Though I agree that in this case for Gelfond-Schneider theorem $i$ is indeed irrational.

Comment: Just to make this self-contained, the Gelfond-Schneider theorem is: If $a$ and $b$ are algebraic with $a \neq 0,1$ and $b$ irrational, then $a^b$ is a transcendental.