# Why contrapositive is wrong for the proof: if $x$ is irrational, then $\sqrt{x}$ is irrational

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Prove or disprove: If $x$ is irrational, then $\sqrt{x}$ is irrational.

$p:\:x$ is irrational

$q: \:\sqrt{x}$ is irrational

Prove by contrapositive: $(p \Rightarrow q) \iff (\lnot q \Rightarrow \lnot p)$

**Proof:** Suppose $\sqrt{x}$ is rational, let $\sqrt{x}=\frac{m}{n}$ for some integer $m, n$, and $n \ne 0$.
Then, $x= (\sqrt{x})^2 = \frac{m^2}{n^2}$. Since $m, n$ are integers, then $\frac{m^2}{n^2}$, so, $x$ is rational. $\blacksquare$

What is wrong with this proof?
Someone gave a counterexample: let $x=-\sqrt{2}$, then $\sqrt{x}$ is not a real number. Hence, irrational. But, my contrapositive proof seems perfectly fine though.

Comment: Your proof assumes that $\sqrt x$ is defined in $\mathbb R$ which means you are assuming that $x\geq 0$. In this case your proof is valid. When $x<0$ there are two square roots of $x$. With either one of the square roots your argument is still valid.

Comment: @Kavi  The premise p that $\sqrt x$ is rational requires $x\geq 0$ to be true. And as the OP proved, in that case, q is also true, so the implication (contrapositive) is true. If $x\lt 0$, $\sqrt x$  is clearly not rational, and in that case, then the contrapositive is trivially true, because a false premise p means $p\to q$ is true, no matter the truth of q.

Comment: Are you supposed to assume that $x \geq 0$?

Comment: No, @riemleb, as I explained, one need not assume $x\geq 0$ for the proof to work.

Comment: No, the proof is fine. If $\sqrt{x}$ is rational, however you define $\sqrt{x}$, then $x$ must be rational as well. Note that $a^2$ is well-defined for any $a \in \mathbb{C}$. Meanwhile $x=-\sqrt{2}$ is not a counterexample for the proof the OP gave, for that matter neither would $x=-2$ be either.

Comment: @amWhy I am saying the same thing as what you said, but in the first sentence I wanted to assume that we are working withing the real line. I corrected it in the second sentence where I said that the equivalence is valid if we use complex numbers. I think we are in full agreement here.

Comment: That someone in my post is the instructor's solution. Maybe he is wrong?

Comment: @amWhy However I do not like use of the notation $\sqrt x$ for a negative number. We have to say which square root is being taken.

Comment: Your proof is valid for all rational numbers and contrapostively equivalent to what you hope to prove. If irrational numbers and their square roots have multiple subcategories, good for them. It doesnt affect your proof at all.

Comment: As I explained, @Kavi, if x is negative then the premise $\sqrt x$ is false, which makes the contrapositive implication true, trivially.

Comment: @user13985 You should not write $\sqrt x$ for negative numbers because there are two square roots. The correct statement is $x$ is rational if and only if **one of the square roots** of $x$ is rational.

Comment: @Kavi  do you not understand that an implication $a\to b$ is true whenever a is false?

Comment: @amWhy  There is a difference bewteen a meaningless startment and  a false statement.

Comment: An irrational number by definition is a real number that is not rational. $x=-\sqrt 2$ is irrational because it is real and not rational. But $\sqrt x$ in this case is not real. Hence it is not an irrational number. So it is a valid counterexample. The statement "x is irrational" is equivalent to "x is real and x is not rational". Hence its negation is actually "x is not real or x is rational"

Comment: @Kavi  do you consider the standard proof that the empty set is a subset of every set, meaningless? Let A be any set. Then the implication, If $x\in \varnothing$ then $x \in A$ hence $\varnothing \subset A$, is absolutely true, even though there is no x in $\varnothing$.  It's not meaningless, it's true.

Comment: @amWhy, the premise of the contrapositive is 'sqrt(x) is not real or sqrt(x) is rational'. It is not false when x is negative. It is true because sqrt(x) is not real.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually "irrational" is only attributed to real numbers. Thus, for negative $x$, property $(q)$ is undefined and it does not make sense to prove $(p) \Rightarrow (q)$ for **all** $x \in \mathbb R$.

You should replace $(q)$ by

$(q')$ If $y$ is real number such that $y^2 = x$, then $y$ is irrational.

Then you proof is correct, but $x = - \sqrt 2$ is no longer a counterexample.

Comment: I guess you meant: if the problem had another condition "$\sqrt{x}$ must be a real number", then my proof is correct?

Comment: @user13985 Yes, that is true!

Comment: Thanks, accepted!

Answer (score 1):

We wish to prove or disprove
$$\text{If } x \text{ is irrational, then } \sqrt{x}\text{ is irrational.}\tag{1}$$

To disprove it, we need only find a counterexample:

$$\text{There exists an }x \text{ such that } x \text{ is irrational and }\sqrt{x}\text{ is not irrational.}$$

A contrapositive proof aims to show that no such counterexample exists.

$$\text{For all }x \text{, if } \sqrt{x}\text{ is not irrational, then }x\text{ is not irrational.}\tag{2}$$

Statement $(2)$ is completely equivalent to statement $(1)$. Your proof of $(2)$ is valid and thus your proof of $(1)$ is complete.

---

What if *not irrational* $\not =$ *rational*?

There is some discussion in the comments about whether imaginary numbers are irrational or not. If imaginary numbers are irrational then, in the domain of complex numbers, the complement of the irrationals is still the rationals. Your proof remains valid. If imaginary numbers are not irrational then the given example is actually a counterexample to (and disproof of) both $(1)$ and $(2)$. Hopefully your professor's proof wasn't much longer than his counterexample.

Comment: The "somone" in my post was the professor. He gave the counterexample, rather than proving it. That's why I felt so strange about myself.

Comment: Both rational and irrational numbers are in $\mathbb{R}$ according to this post https://math.stackexchange.com/a/823981/44802. Assuming that, then my proof is perhaps wrong. And the counterexample "If $x=-\sqrt{2}$, then $\sqrt{x}$ is imaginary" is valid to disprove.

Answer (score 0):

An irrational number by definition is a real number that is not rational. $x=−\sqrt 2$ is irrational because it is real and not rational. But $\sqrt x$ in this case is not real. Hence it is not an irrational number. So it is a valid counterexample. The statement "x is irrational" is equivalent to "x is real and x is not rational". Hence its negation is actually "x is not real or x is rational"

If I label the set of irrational numbers as: $I = \mathbb{R}$\ $\mathbb{Q}$

Then we can rewrite your initial statement as:

$x \in I \implies \sqrt x  \in I$

The contrapositive is:

$\sqrt x \notin I \implies x  \notin I$

We can see that $x = -\sqrt 2$ is a valid counterexample to these two equivalent statements.

Comment: That's what I am thinking, but people here on SE seems to say the proof is right and counterexample is not needed.